# BDD SpecFlow Scenario types

Tags: bdd, specflow, gherkin

I have been writing some BDD Scenarios and writing automated tests from them for some time but I am still in a phase of discovery really.

I can see that Visual Studio gives me the option to write a Scenario, a Scenario Outline or a Scenario Template.

I've figured out the difference between Scenario and Scenario Outline (the first runs once and the second one will run for as many examples as you put - please correct me or add something if I am wrong).

However I found little information about "Scenario Template". Could anyone explain the difference? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Scenario Outline* and *Scenario Template* are just synonyms. There is no difference. Both define `scenario_outline` step. There are several synonyms in English SpecFlow keywords.  E.g *Examples* and *Scenarios* or *Feature* and *Business Need*. Different synonyms are defined for different languages, and specified in [internationalization](https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin/blob/master/lib/gherkin/i18n.json) file. E.g. for English:

```
"en": {
  "name": "English",
  "native": "English",
  "feature": "Feature|Business Need|Ability",
  "background": "Background",
  "scenario": "Scenario",
  "scenario_outline": "Scenario Outline|Scenario Template",
  "examples": "Examples|Scenarios",
  "given": "*|Given",
  "when": "*|When",
  "then": "*|Then",
  "and": "*|And",
  "but": "*|But"
}
```

For other languages there can be other synonyms. E.g. German and Russian have three different names of Given step:

```
"given": "*|Angenommen|Gegeben sei|Gegeben seien"
"given": "*|Допустим|Дано|Пусть"
```

Comment: That's cool that you can use different languages, I never knew that!

Comment: @shmish111 yep, main point of SpecFlow is creating live documentation, which stakeholder/business user would understand. Sometimes its better to use native language of business user